# SQL Server: Insert if Current Date > endDate

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

Basically what I need to do is to insert into table `Reservation` a `vehicleID`, `startDate` and `endDate`.

I can do that fine but I'd like to validate it so that it cannot be inserted for that `vehicleID` if the current date is `<= endDate` as currently I can just keep adding to the `Reservation` table on the same `vehicleID`

This is just the simple insert SQL statement.

```
strInsert = String.Format("Insert into Reservation (VehicleID, startDate, enddate) VALUES ('{0}','{1}','{2}')", vID, now, now5)
```

Regards.

Comment: I hope you're not going to deploy that string formatter without scrubbing the data inputs. You should be using SQLParameters instead, otherwise you may be ripe for SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Oh no, this will not have any commercial requirements, its just work on an intranet.

Comment: Still, that's not an excuse to use bad practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about not attempting an insert if today's date is less than the enddate you are inserting?

```
If Date.Today <= now5 Then
   Throw New Exception("Invalid Date")
Else
  strInsert = String.Format("Insert into Reservation (VehicleID, startDate, enddate) VALUES ('{0}','{1}','{2}')", vID, now, now5)
End If
```

**UPDATE**

If you are implementing this all in SQL, then I recommend using a stored procedure, but in either case the logic is the same. Check to see if any reservations exist that overlap today and if they do, throw an exception from SQL.

Note that `GETDATE()` is not quite the right value to use since it returns the current timestamp, but without know how the values are stored, it is used as an approximation and can be cleaned up later.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE s_AddReservation
    @VehicleID   INT ,
    @StartDate   DATETIME ,
    @EndDate     DATETIME
AS
    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1
                FROM Reservation
               WHERE VehicleID = @VehicleID
                 AND StartDate <= GETDATE()
                 AND EndDate >= GETDATE())
      BEGIN
        RAISERROR('This care has already been rented', 16, 1);
      END
    ELSE
      BEGIN
        Insert into Reservation (VehicleID, startDate, enddate) VALUES (@VehicleID, @StartDate, @EndDate)
      END
GO
```

To call this stored procedure from your code:

```
var oCommand = new SqlCommand('s_AddReservation', conn);
oCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VehicleID", vID);
oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", now);
oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", now5);

oCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: The if/else isn't required as the exception will break the loop anyhow.

Comment: @MatthewPK: True, but I like to structure it like that in case the implementation is changed down the road by someone who isn't paying complete attention (this has happened dozens of times that I know of). For example, if you want to set a byref errormessage parameter in the method call, you can change the throw exception to a set of the parameter and the remaining code won't get accidentally executed.

Comment: Thanks for the help but now and now5 are datetime.now and datetime.now.addminutes(5) therefore it will always throw that exception.

What I need is an SQL statement where it searches the Reservation table first to check that VehicleID's last reservation and see if datetime.now > endDate.

thanks!

Comment: @CraigWilliams: Update the answer with an SQL implementation. I have it stored procedure format, but you could flatten it out to dynamic sql if you want.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

I haven't used stored procedures before, do I create one with the code you put in the update?

Comment: @CraigWilliams: I have updated the answer to show creation of the SP and calling from your code. I would strongly recommend this approach for all of your database interaction; it will remove the possibility of SQL injection, improve performance, and I think is generally easier to work with.

Comment: Thanks a lot, would I also have to remove my previous strInsert command in the code tags I put in my OP?

Comment: Perfect, the error comes up when I try to reserve the vehicleID twice within the 5 minutes.

Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. And welcome to stackoverflow. Keep in mind that if an answer solves or helps you solve your question, you should click on the checkmark and up arrow next to the question so that future visitors to the question know this is what helped you.

Answer (score 1):

You can enforce the condition with a `where` if you use `select` instead of `values`:

```
insert  Reservation 
        (VehicleID, startDate, enddate) 
select  '{0}', '{1}', '{2}'
where   getdate() > '{2}'
```

Comment: Hello all, thanks for the help. Basically what I need to do is to check the reservation table first to see if there's a reservation already for the VehicleID, then do a GETDATE() check against the endDate to confirm that GETDATE() is > than enddate.

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this with constraints and a trigger so no matter how you insert or update your data, the database will enforce your logic.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Reservation(
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    VehicleId int NOT NULL,
    StartDate datetime NOT NULL,
    EndDate datetime NULL,
 CONSTRAINT pk_dbo_reservation PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (Id ASC),
 CONSTRAINT uq_dbo_reservation UNIQUE CLUSTERED (VehicleId ASC, StartDate ASC)
)
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Reservation WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT ck_dbo_reservation_startdate_before_enddate CHECK (StartDate < EndDate)
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Reservation ADD CONSTRAINT df_dbo_reservation_startdate DEFAULT (GETDATE()) FOR StartDate
GO
---------------------------------------
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trg_insupd_ReservationNoOverlap ON dbo.Reservation
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
IF EXISTS (
    -- reservation is already active during the new time frame
    SELECT b.VehicleId
    FROM   dbo.Reservation b
           INNER JOIN inserted ins
             ON b.VehicleId = ins.VehicleId
                AND b.Id <> ins.Id
    WHERE  ( b.StartDate <= ins.StartDate
             AND ( b.EndDate IS NULL
                    OR b.EndDate > ins.StartDate ) )
            OR ( b.StartDate > ins.StartDate
                 AND ( ins.EndDate IS NULL
                        OR ins.EndDate > b.StartDate ) )
)
BEGIN
RAISERROR ('Dates cannot overlap for vehicle reservation.', 16, 1) WITH SETERROR;
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
RETURN
END
GO
```

Test cases:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Reservation (VehicleId, StartDate, EndDate) VALUES (1, '12/01/2011', '12/06/2011') -- ok
INSERT INTO dbo.Reservation (VehicleId, StartDate, EndDate) VALUES (1, '12/06/2011', '12/08/2011') -- ok
INSERT INTO dbo.Reservation (VehicleId, StartDate, EndDate) VALUES (1, '12/03/2011', '12/04/2011') -- not ok (overlaps)

INSERT INTO dbo.Reservation (VehicleId, StartDate, EndDate) VALUES (1, '12/08/2011', NULL) -- ok (open-ended)
INSERT INTO dbo.Reservation (VehicleId, StartDate, EndDate) VALUES (1, '11/20/2011', '11/26/2011') -- ok
INSERT INTO dbo.Reservation (VehicleId, StartDate, EndDate) VALUES (1, '11/28/2011', NULL) -- not ok (overlaps)
```